# How is a straight arbor retained and engaged on a drill press?

Tags: drill

On something like a drill press, how is a straight shank arbor retained and engaged? I don't see a clear way that this is accomplished from photos.

[image]

https://allindustrial.com/all-industrial-49623-1-2-to-6jt-straight-shank-drill-chuck-hardened-jt6-jacobs-taper/

Comment: Recess is for set screw?

Comment: @VolframKOn Without a flat? (as far as I can tell) Seems unlikely.

Comment: I see references to set screws with straight shanks when I search the subject. Like you I don't see how you would retain these by other means :)

Comment: @VolframK Me neither, but I expect a flat if it's supposed to be a piece of high torque precision tooling. I found no references at all which is why I resorted to asking here. The wrong search results kept coming up. Can you link?

Comment: @VolframK Usually a recess like that one is just to reduce the area that needs to be machined. On a lathe spindle, for example, you'd have bearings at each end, but not in the middle, so there's no need to machine the middle.

Comment: @Caleb but lathe time is the same! I thought it must have some purpose in use, but maybe not. Some posters suggest that it is only to provide area for printing specs lol

Comment: @Al Rahat Trading I would have go into work and look at the brand, but it is not a big box store brand. It is a Solberga drill press. Made in Sweden for metal working. https://www.akhurst.com/product/solberga-se2025-series-geared-head-drill-presses/

Comment: And it does list our drill press as having a Morse Taper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On something like a drill press, how is a straight shank arbor retained and engaged?

I think it's meant to be held in a collet or tool holder for a milling machine. The shank is 1/2", which is a common size for an end mill. Here's [a tool holder for a 1/2" end mill](https://cdn0.grizzly.com/pics/jpeg288/t/t25713.jpg):

[image: grizzly nt40 mill holder]

Note that the description for the arbor you linked to says "no drawbar." A drawbar is a mechanism for pulling a tool holder into a milling machine's spindle, so they're clearly speaking to a milling machine-using audience.

Comment: Is that what it is? if that's what it was it would make more sense. However, a Morse taper also has a draw bar. Our drill press has one and we use it without the drawbar (unless I misremember and it's a Jacobs Taper).

Comment: @DKNguyen Another option would be to press bearings onto the machined areas. The spindle in my lathe looks a lot like the straight portion of the arbor you show. But I don't think that arbor is meant to be used that way because there's no obvious way to drive it. That tells me that the straight part is meant to be squeezed in something like a collet or maybe a 3-jaw chuck on a lathe.

Comment: Perhaps my memory was off about the drill press we have being a morse taper. I'll have to check.

Comment: @DKNguyen If it's a woodworking drill press, it almost certainly has a morse taper. If it's a combination mill/drill kind of thing, it might well have a draw bar. But I wonder if you were thinking of the drift that's used to help unseat the arbor?

Comment: It's a metal working drill press. If I remember, right the guy who uses it sticks a wedge into a slot that runs in the side and hits it with a mallet and it comes right out. And when he installs it, he just shoves it in with this hand.

Comment: @DKNguyen Sounds like a Morse taper to me. A drawbar actually grabs the tool and pulls it into the spindle. The wedge he uses is called a *drift* or *drill drift*.

Comment: Yeah. I'm still asking about the item in the photo above though. So collets or chucks huh?

Comment: @DKNguyen Same as something like a drill bit or router bit.

Comment: Our drill press is a Solberga and it does have a Morse taper.